# How to add property to an object?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I have an object who is created dynamically and some times it has the property `theCtns.services["example"].expose` who is an array and some times it hasn't. It's normal there is no bugs here.

Then I have a method that do:

```
if($('#labelExpose').children().length > 1){
  $('#labelExpose').children('input').each(function (index) {
    if(this.value){
      console.log("value of expose field number:" + index  );
      console.log(this.value);
      theCtns.services[ctn].expose[index] =  this.value;
     }
  });
}else{
  delete theCtns.services[ctn].depends_on;
}
```

But I have the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined` because there isn't `expose` but it should creates it with the `= this.value` right ?

So how can I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm pretty sure your issue is that you need to create the property first and then assign a value to the first index.

Try replacing this line:

```
theCtns.services[ctn].expose[index] =  this.value;
```

With these two lines:

```
theCtns.services[ctn].expose = theCtns.services[ctn].expose || []; // if it already exists, it will set it to itself, if not it will set it to an empty array
theCtns.services[ctn].expose[index] =  this.value; // this will not set the item at that index
```

Comment: I try like this and I come back here after

Comment: No no I test with your answer but I need 10min to test

Comment: Okay, no problem. You just need to first assign the property as an array, and then you can start adding things to that array.

Answer (score 0):

Here theCtns.services[ctn].expose is undefined, that is why you are getting this error. To avoid this error you can add a check like

```
if(theCtns.services[ctn].expose) {
   theCtns.services[ctn].expose[index] =  this.value;
}
```

Or you should define theCtns.services[ctn].expose before assign a value to it.